# Postting request to download file using python-requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm trying to create multipart/form-data with python requests.
The solution ought to return big csv file.

But I have problems with posting such request (raw from Fiddler):

```
POST http://fix-cloud.sbis.ru/view_log/service/sbis-rpc-service300.dll?raw_file_result HTTP/1.1
Host: fix-cloud.sbis.ru
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 579
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://fix-cloud.sbis.ru
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0FyoqFD3QVSl0bly
Referer: http://fix-cloud.sbis.ru/cloud.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: _ym_uid=1455544058672406990; __utma=60092399.1077522409.1455548286.1455548286.1455548286.1; __utmz=60092399.1455548286.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); timeToCheck=Wed%2C%2024%20Feb%202016%2016%3A18%3A51%20GMT; param=viewer; did=fb1a4666-e652-4f87-abb4-8fbc445bc20d; rightshash=c7b7b64c088c681b0ff84407076cad18; CpsUserId=; tz=-180; RT=; su=00000001-00056a83; sid=00000001-00056a83-00ba-6847661894264e9c

------WebKitFormBoundary0FyoqFD3QVSl0bly
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Запрос"

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","protocol":4,"method":"ЖурналСообщений.Выгрузить","params":{"Параметры":{"s":[{"t":"Строка","n":"ВремяОт"},{"t":"Строка","n":"ВремяДо"},{"t":"Строка","n":"Группа"}],"d":["2016-02-24 19:18:03.500+03","2016-02-24 19:19:03.500+03","Основной сервис inside"],"_type":"record"},"fileDownloadToken":7140344178769737},"id":"4117712937295437"}
------WebKitFormBoundary0FyoqFD3QVSl0bly--
```

This doesn't work correct. When I'm trying to get very large file, server returns the answer 504.

```
r = s.post(csv_url, headers = post_headers, data = json.dumps(data))
```

That solution doesn't work in any way. It answered as 500

```
r = s.post(csv_url, headers = post_headers, files = {'Запрос':(None, json.dumps(data), None)})
```

Curl command

```
curl 'http://fix-cloud.sbis.ru/view_log/service/sbis-rpc-service300.dll?raw_file_result' -H 'Host: fix-cloud.sbis.ru' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Referer: http://fix-cloud.sbis.ru/cloud.html' -H 'Cookie: param=viewer; CpsUserId=; did=238ebefa-ec52-4c41-a1d7-8a14fcfdeae4; timeToCheck=Thu%2C%2025%20Feb%202016%2010%3A48%3A55%20GMT; rightshash=c7b7b64c088c681b0ff84407076cad18; tz=-180; RT=; sid=00000001-00056a83-00ba-ffbbb027145646c3; su=00000001-00056a83' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------12195194351941' --data-binary $'-----------------------------12195194351941\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="\u0417\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441"\r\n\r\n{"jsonrpc":"2.0","protocol":4,"method":"\u0416\u0443\u0440\u043d\u0430\u043b\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0439.\u0412\u044b\u0433\u0440\u0443\u0437\u0438\u0442\u044c","params":{"\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0430\u043c\u0435\u0442\u0440\u044b":{"s":[{"t":"\u0421\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0430","n":"\u0412\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f\u041e\u0442"},{"t":"\u0421\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0430","n":"\u0412\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f\u0414\u043e"},{"t":"\u0421\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0430","n":"\u0413\u0440\u0443\u043f\u043f\u0430"}],"d":["2016-02-25 14:40:02.900+03","2016-02-25 14:40:02.900+03","\u041e\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u0441\u0435\u0440\u0432\u0438\u0441 inside"],"_type":"record"},"fileDownloadToken":36597679759578120},"id":"9150478717440579"}\r\n-----------------------------12195194351941--\r\n'
```

Comment: Why don't you include the Google document in your answer? Was this done using curl?

Comment: Stackoverflow thinks that I'm posting urls. I can post only 2 urls. I don't use curl. In this solution I ought to use python-requests

Comment: A 50x means your server responds with an error. So your request does something the server doesn't like.

Comment: I undestand this. But I need some advice, how to write this post requiest to get 200

Comment: @VasiliyKirnos Did you manage to perform the request in your browser? In this case, you could use the "copy as curl" from Firefox or Chrome. Then you could try it in curl and see if it works, and that would allow you to see the difference between curl and requests which don't send the exact same request by default. And some servers are too picky with multipart form data.

Comment: @QuentinPradet curl wrote a lot of errors. curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: text
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: *
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: q=0.01'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: gzip,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: deflate'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'

Comment: Can you paste the curl command?

Comment: @QuentinPradet I add cur command to first messeage

Comment: The only error is `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: fix-cloud.sbis.ru` and I can't resolve the host either.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) for the documentation.

The second entry in the file tuple should be an open file handle. Instead, you send a string `json.dumps(data)`. Write the string to a file (or a filelike buffer that requests can read from), then send that instead.

Comment: I generate file and write down the json.dumps(data).This solution adds  ` Content-Disposition: form-data; name*=utf-8''%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81; filename="temp.txt" ` But I don't need filename field. It returns 500

Answer (score 0):

The problem has another side: ForeFront stop me any time when I'm trying to send requiest more then for 2 minutes. And with python-requests I can't solve it.

Thats why the easiest solution is to sent more then one post request and to get many small files.